# Pattern Matching with Mismatch

Tags: java, strings

I have been using a slightly modified Hamming Distance algorithm for approximate String Matching for patterns and wondering if there is something better out there. The *t* being the length of the text and *p* being the length of the pattern the worst case is roughly O(t*p). Which from looking at other Fuzzy String matching seems to be in norm.

```
    final int mismatches = 1;
    final String text = "bubbles";
    final String pattern = "bu";    

    for(int iter = 0; iter < text.length() - pattern.length() + 1; iter++)
    {
        int missed = 0;
        int ator = 0;

        do
        {
            if(text.charAt(iter + ator) != pattern.charAt(ator))
            {
                missed++;
            }
        }while(++ator < pattern.length() && missed <= mismatches);

        if(missed <= mismatches)
        {
            System.out.println("Index: " + iter + " Pattern: " + text.substring(iter, iter + pattern.length()));
        }
    }
```

The output being indexes 0 bu, 2 bb, and 3 bl. The last two being mismatches with the tolerance of 1.

Comment: Please describe your slight modification: Hamming distance is only defined for equal-length strings.

Comment: Furthermore, *what’s the question here?* If you just want your code reviewed – it looks good, there’s nothing obvious that I’d change, except obviously to put the functionality in its own method.

Comment: The modification is that it can work for Strings of different lengths. Sorry I did not put that much emphasis on the question. For this type of pattern matching with substations but not also insertions (like a Levenshtein Distance), is this code reasonable, is there something that could be changed, or is there a more appropriate algorithm?

Comment: Looks like ['Save Humanity' Challenge](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4f304a3d84b5e) and already answered [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13383/approximate-string-matching-interview-question/13388#13388).

Answer (score 2):

It looks fine. Some readability improvements:

1. I'd rename some variables first:

   - `mismatches` should be `tolerance`, `mismatchTolerance` or `allowedMismatches`. For me `mismatches` sounds like a counter but it never changes which is confusing somehow.
   - `iter` and `ator` do not make the code easier to read. `textIndex` (maybe `searchIndex`) and `patternIndex` would be better since they are more meaningful and explains the purpose.
2. Then extract out some named variables like

   - `final int textIndexMax = text.length() - pattern.length() + 1;`
   - `final char textChar = text.charAt(textIndex + patternIndex);`
   - `final char patternChar = pattern.charAt(patternIndex);`
   - `final String match = text.substring(textIndex, textIndex + pattern.length());`

   Reference: *Chapter 6. Composing Methods*, *Introduce Explaining Variable* in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler

   > Put the result of the expression, or parts of the expression, 
   >   in a temporary variable with a name that explains the purpose.
3. The condition of the `do-while` loop could be rewritten as a usual (and a not so complex, therefore an easier to understand and less error-prone) `for (i = 0; i < x; i++)` loop and a `break` statement.

Here is my version:

```
final int mismatchTolerance = 1;
final String text = "bubbles";
final String pattern = "bu";

final int textIndexMax = text.length() - pattern.length() + 1;
for (int textIndex = 0; textIndex < textIndexMax; textIndex++) {
    int missed = 0;

    for (int patternIndex = 0; patternIndex < pattern.length(); patternIndex++) {
        final char textChar = text.charAt(textIndex + patternIndex);
        final char patternChar = pattern.charAt(patternIndex);
        if (textChar != patternChar) {
            missed++;
        }
        if (missed > mismatchTolerance) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (missed <= mismatchTolerance) {
        final String match = text.substring(textIndex, textIndex + pattern.length());
        System.out.println("Index: " + textIndex + " Match: " + match);
    }
}
```